# Why did NASA divide Expedition 13 into two parts?

Tags: iss, nasa

Up until ISS Expedition 12, all are single parts, but why did NASA divide Expedition 13 into two parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up [until Expedition 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_International_Space_Station_expeditions), everyone on the station arrived and departed at the same time. Expedition 13 was the first one that did not occur. I believe this was in part due to spaceflight participant Anousheh Ansari visiting with the mission that brought the [Expedition 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_14) crew up to the ISS. [Thomas Reiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Reiter) instead returned on the Space Shuttle, as it was then flying again (It had stopped after the Columbia issue in 2003).